# Ruby condition within HAML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

Here is my best attempt that does not work:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  - if params[:filtered] == "a"
  highlightLink(0);
  - elsif params[:filtered] == "b"
  highlightLink(1); 
  - elsif params[:filtered] == "c"
  highlightLink(2);  
  });
```

What should I do so that my above attempt works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example you can try something like following

```
  num = params[:filtered] == "a" ? 0 : (params[:filtered] == "b" ? 1 : 2)
  a= %(:javascript $(document).ready(function(){ highlightLink(#{num})}); )
```